# Create new DataFrame from dictionary in cells of old Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
print(df_master)

Authors              | Codes | ID     | Year
[{first_name: 'fn1', | 11111 | id0001 | 2019
  last_name: 'ln1'}, 
 {first_name: 'fn2', 
  last_name: 'ln2'}]
[{first_name: 'fn3', | 22222 | id0002 | 2019
  last_name: 'ln3'}]
```

I want to create a new Dataframe from the Authors column that looks like this:

```
print(df_authors)

First Name | Last Name | Codes | ID     | Year
'fn1'      | 'ln1'     | 11111 | id0001 | 2019
'fn2'      | 'ln2'     | 11111 | id0001 | 2019
'fn3'      | 'ln3'     | 22222 | id0002 | 2020
```

At the moment I can't even access the dictionary from the cells. I tried:

```
df_dim['Authors'].apply(pd.Series)
```

But I get the same column.
* I think the problem is that the dict is stored as string.

Answer (score 0):

Create new dictionary in list comprehension with `ast.literal_eval` for convert strings repr to dictionaries and `join` to original DataFrame:

```
import ast

df1 = (pd.DataFrame([{**y, **{'i':k}} 
                     for k, v in df.pop('Authors').items() 
                     for y in ast.literal_eval(v)]).set_index('i'))

print (df1)
  first_name last_name
i                     
0        fn1       ln1
0        fn2       ln2
1        fn3       ln3

df = df.join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Codes      ID  Year first_name last_name
0  11111  id0001  2019        fn1       ln1
1  11111  id0001  2019        fn2       ln2
2  22222  id0002  2019        fn3       ln3
```

Comment: it kind of works. It's all good until printing df1. The line where df and df1 are joined doesn't work. 'first_name' and 'last_name' are all NaNs

Comment: @DCN - Can you try `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`  before my solution?

Comment: @DCN - Are data confidental?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Return first_names and last_names
def get_first_last_names(authors):
    first_names = []
    last_names = []
    for a in authors:
            first_names.append(a['first_name'])
            last_names.append(a['last_name'])
    return first_names, last_names

first_names, last_names = get_first_last_names(df['Authors'].values)
# Add new columns and set values
df['first_name'] = first_names
df['last_name'] = last_names
# Drop Authors column
df.drop(columns=['Authors'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the dataframe reads the "Authors" as a string and not a dict.

Comment: Convert it to JSON Object.

import json
j_author = json.loads(a)